# Tangent Line of Function of Two Variables

Tags: calculus

$f(x, y) = x^4 + y^4 + 2 x^{2}y^{2} − 2 x^2 + 2 y^2 + 1$

i- What are the domain and range of the function? Is the domain closed? open?
bounded? Give brief justifications to your answers.

ii- Draw the level curve passing through $(\sqrt{2}, 0)$.

iii- Find the tangent line (or lines, if there is more than one) to the level curve from
part (ii) at $(0,0)$.

iv- Find the maximum value of the function $g(x, y) = y^2 − x^2$ when it is restricted
to the curve in part (ii).

Hint: You might find polar coordinates useful for some parts of this question.

Comment: What have you tried? You should not ask multiple problems in the homework at once without showing what you have done.

Comment: This isn’t a homework-solving site.

Comment: It was not a homework I was reviewing